# How to read a tag without remove it and tag again after format

Tags: android, tags, nfc, ndef

I'm writing a program that writing messages into Factory-New tags

```
public void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
     Tag tagFromIntent = intent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);

     Ndef ndefTag = Ndef.get(tagFromIntent);   //ndefTag will be null here

      .
      .
      .
      //read message , return if correct ,continue if empty or not correct
      .
      .
      .

     if (ndefTag == null) {

                //  try to format the Tag in NDEF


                NdefFormatable nForm = NdefFormatable.get(tagFromIntent);

                if (nForm != null) {

                    nForm.connect();

                    nForm.format(message);

                    nForm.close();

                }


            } else {

                ndefTag.connect();

                if (!ndefTag.isWritable()) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Locked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    locked = true;
                    //ndefTag.close();
                } else {

                    ndefTag.writeNdefMessage(message);

                    //ndefTag.makeReadOnly();
                    //ndefTag.close();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Write success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }


            }


}
```

After format the tag with message, I want to check the message is correct

But "intent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG)" still get the same TAG that without written message so I have to remove tag and tag it again

Is there any way to call NFC sensor to tag again?

Or a better way to format and write -> read?